# How to copy text to X primary selection only when visual mode is started with the mouse?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, os-clipboard

At the moment, if I use Visual mode, whenever I select a block of text using the keyboard it ends up on my X primary selection (ie the clipboard that is filled using the mouse). Even if I just select the text then hit escape it still ends up there.

I don't want this, as I can just as well use `"*y` when I want this in my primary selection. However, selecting text with the mouse is still a useful X idiom that I want to work. Is it possible to make visual mode put this text on the clipboard but ONLY when the mouse is used to select it?

Comment: See `:h clipboard` (autoselect) and `:h x11`. Also `:h guioptions_a`